# Obtain the information needed to make an API call from a web page that calls it

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to extract the elements of the ratings from [the following web page](https://www.sephora.fr/p/burberry-body---eau-de-parfum-232743.html):

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Which code is the next:

```html
<ol data-bv-v="contentItemCollection:2" class="bv-content-list bv-content-list-reviews">
   <li data-bv-v="contentItem:9" class="bv-content-item bv-content-top-review bv-content-review bv-content-loaded" itemprop="review" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" data-content-id="Reviews-158638580">
      <div data-bv-v="inlineProfile:13" class="bv-author-profile">
         <div class="bv-inline-profile">
            <div class="bv-author-avatar">
               <div class="bv-author-avatar-nickname">
                  <div class="bv-content-author-name" role="presentation">
                     <button type="button" class="bv-author bv-fullprofile-popup-target bv-focusable" aria-label="Voir le profil de oceaned03.">
                        <h3>oceaned03</h3>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bv-popup-prosnap-userinfo bv-contains-profile-button">
               <div class="bv-content-author-name" role="presentation">
                  <button type="button" class="bv-author bv-fullprofile-popup-target bv-focusable" aria-label="Voir le profil de oceaned03.">
                     <h3>oceaned03</h3>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-author-location">  <span> Clermont Ferrand </span>  </div>
               <div class="bv-author-userstats">
                  <ul class="bv-author-userstats-list" role="list">
                     <li class="bv-author-userstats-reviews">  <span class="bv-author-userstats-data"> Avis : </span> <span class="bv-author-userstats-value">1</span> </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-userstats-votes">   </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-content-author-badges">
                  <ul class="bv-content-author-badges-list" role="presentation">              </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-author-userinfo">
                  <ul role="list">
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv bv-first ">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Sexe </span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">une femme</span> 
                     </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv  ">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Age</span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">18-24 ans</span> 
                     </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv  ">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Couleur des yeux</span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">Bleus</span> 
                     </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv  bv-last">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Type de peau</span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">Sèche</span> 
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bv-content-item-author-profile-offset bv-content-item-author-profile-offset-on">
         <div class="bv-content-container">
            <div class="bv-content-core ">
               <div class="bv-content-header">
                  <div class="bv-content-data-summary">
                     <div class="bv-content-badges-container">
                        <ul class="bv-badge-summary bv-badge-first bv-badge-top-three" role="presentation">
                           <li class="bv-badge-image bv-badge-content-loyaltyyes--im-a-beauty-insider" role="presentation"> <img src="https://display.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/static/Sephora-FR/main_site/951/3232/fr_FR/images/badgeImages/loyaltyyes--im-a-beauty-insider.png" alt="Carte White" title="Carte White"> </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="bv-content-header-meta">
                        <span class="bv-content-rating bv-rating-ratio" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                           <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">
                           <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
                           <span class="bv-rating-stars-container"> <abbr title="5 sur 5 étoiles." class="bv-rating bv-rating-stars bv-rating-stars-off" aria-hidden="true"> ★★★★★ </abbr> <abbr title="5 sur 5 étoiles." class="bv-rating-max bv-rating-stars bv-rating-stars-on bv-width-from-rating-stats-100" aria-hidden="true"> ★★★★★ </abbr> <span class="bv-off-screen">5 sur 5 étoiles.</span> </span> 
                        </span>
                        <div class="bv-content-meta-wrapper">
                           <div class="bv-content-meta" role="presentation">
                              <div class="bv-content-reference-data bv-content-author-name">
                                 <button type="button" class="bv-author bv-fullprofile-popup-target bv-focusable" aria-label="Voir le profil de oceaned03." itemprop="author">
                                    <h3>oceaned03</h3>
                                 </button>
                                 <div class="bv-content-datetime" role="presentation">
                                    <meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2020-06-24">
                                    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2020-06-24">
                                    <span class="bv-content-datetime-dot" aria-hidden="true">·</span> <span class="bv-content-datetime-stamp">il y a 5 mois &nbsp;</span> 
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="bv-content-title-container">
                        <h3 class="bv-content-title" itemprop="headline">    Satisfaite   </h3>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-content-details-offset-off">
                  <div class="bv-content-summary">
                     <div class="bv-content-summary-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
                        <div class="bv-content-summary-body-text">
                           <p>Très contente de mon achat. Je cherchais ce parfum depuis un temps en magasin et je suis heureuse qu’il soit disponible en ligne il sent tellement bon !! En plus en promo, génial ! <br>Livraison très rapide !</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bv-content-data">
                           <div class="bv-content-product-questions">  </div>
                           <div class="bv-content-tag-dimensions">  </div>
                           <ul class="bv-content-data-recommend-yes">
                              <li class="bv-content-data-label-container"> <span class="bv-content-data-icon" aria-hidden="true">✔</span> <span class="bv-content-data-label">Oui</span>, </li>
                              <li class="bv-content-data-value">  je recommande ce produit. </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="bv-content-actions-container bv-active-feedback">
            <div data-bv-v="feedback:12" class="bv-feedback-container">
               <div class="bv-content-feedback-vote bv-content-feedback-vote-active" role="group" aria-label="Utilité du contenu">
                  <div class="bv-content-feedback-vote-request">
                     <p>Avez-vous trouvé cet avis utile ?</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="bv-content-feedback-btn-container"> <button type="button" class="bv-content-btn bv-content-btn-feedback-yes bv-focusable" aria-label="1&nbsp;personne a trouvé cet avis utile. Oui, review de oceaned03 est utile."> <span aria-hidden="true"> Oui · <span class="bv-content-btn-count" aria-hidden="true">1</span> </span> </button> <button type="button" class="bv-content-btn bv-content-btn-feedback-no bv-focusable" aria-label="0&nbsp;personne a trouvé cet avis inutile. Non, review de oceaned03 n'est pas utile."> <span aria-hidden="true"> Non · <span class="bv-content-btn-count" aria-hidden="true">0</span> </span> </button> </div>
                  <div class="bv-content-feedback-vote bv-content-feedback-vote-active"> <button type="button" class="bv-content-report-btn bv-focusable" aria-label="Marquer «&nbsp;Satisfaite&nbsp;» de oceaned03 comme inapproprié.">   Signalez un contenu inapproprié  </button> </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="bv-inline-form-container"></div>
         <div data-bv-v="secondaryContentList:10" class="bv-secondary-content-list">
            <ol data-bv-v="secondaryContentItemCollection:11" class="bv-content-list bv-content-list-clientresponses" role="presentation">
            </ol>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li data-bv-v="contentItem:14" class="bv-content-item bv-content-top-review bv-content-review bv-content-loaded" itemprop="review" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" data-content-id="Reviews-156726085">
      <div data-bv-v="inlineProfile:18" class="bv-author-profile">
         <div class="bv-inline-profile">
            <div class="bv-author-avatar">
               <div class="bv-author-avatar-nickname">
                  <div class="bv-content-author-name" role="presentation">
                     <button type="button" class="bv-author bv-fullprofile-popup-target bv-focusable" aria-label="Voir le profil de Jo56.">
                        <h3>Jo56</h3>
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bv-popup-prosnap-userinfo bv-contains-profile-button">
               <div class="bv-content-author-name" role="presentation">
                  <button type="button" class="bv-author bv-fullprofile-popup-target bv-focusable" aria-label="Voir le profil de Jo56.">
                     <h3>Jo56</h3>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-author-location">  <span> Lorient </span>  </div>
               <div class="bv-author-userstats">
                  <ul class="bv-author-userstats-list" role="list">
                     <li class="bv-author-userstats-reviews">  <span class="bv-author-userstats-data"> Avis : </span> <span class="bv-author-userstats-value">3</span> </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-userstats-votes">   </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-content-author-badges">
                  <ul class="bv-content-author-badges-list" role="presentation">              </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-author-userinfo">
                  <ul role="list">
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv bv-first ">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Sexe </span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">une femme</span> 
                     </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv  ">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Age</span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">18-24 ans</span> 
                     </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv  ">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Couleur des yeux</span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">Marrons</span> 
                     </li>
                     <li class="bv-author-cdv  bv-last">
                        <!-- UIA-7763 - removed default display so only translated strings matched by FB will display; can't remove defaultDisplay field entirely due to compilation errors, so used a value of '' --> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-data">Type de peau</span> <span class="bv-author-userinfo-value">Sèche</span> 
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bv-content-item-author-profile-offset bv-content-item-author-profile-offset-on">
         <div class="bv-content-container">
            <div class="bv-content-core ">
               <div class="bv-content-header">
                  <div class="bv-content-data-summary">
                     <div class="bv-content-badges-container">
                        <ul class="bv-badge-summary bv-badge-first bv-badge-top-three" role="presentation">
                           <li class="bv-badge-image bv-badge-content-loyaltyyes--im-a-vib-rouge" role="presentation"> <img src="https://display.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/static/Sephora-FR/main_site/951/3232/fr_FR/images/badgeImages/loyaltyyes--im-a-vib-rouge.png" alt="Carte Gold" title="Carte Gold"> </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="bv-content-header-meta">
                        <span class="bv-content-rating bv-rating-ratio" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                           <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">
                           <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
                           <span class="bv-rating-stars-container"> <abbr title="5 sur 5 étoiles." class="bv-rating bv-rating-stars bv-rating-stars-off" aria-hidden="true"> ★★★★★ </abbr> <abbr title="5 sur 5 étoiles." class="bv-rating-max bv-rating-stars bv-rating-stars-on bv-width-from-rating-stats-100" aria-hidden="true"> ★★★★★ </abbr> <span class="bv-off-screen">5 sur 5 étoiles.</span> </span> 
                        </span>
                        <div class="bv-content-meta-wrapper">
                           <div class="bv-content-meta" role="presentation">
                              <div class="bv-content-reference-data bv-content-author-name">
                                 <button type="button" class="bv-author bv-fullprofile-popup-target bv-focusable" aria-label="Voir le profil de Jo56." itemprop="author">
                                    <h3>Jo56</h3>
                                 </button>
                                 <div class="bv-content-datetime" role="presentation">
                                    <meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2020-05-22">
                                    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2020-05-22">
                                    <span class="bv-content-datetime-dot" aria-hidden="true">·</span> <span class="bv-content-datetime-stamp">il y a 6 mois &nbsp;</span> 
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="bv-content-title-container">
                        <h3 class="bv-content-title" itemprop="headline">    Excellent   </h3>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="bv-content-details-offset-off">
                  <div class="bv-content-summary">
                     <div class="bv-content-summary-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
                        <div class="bv-content-summary-body-text">
                           <p>J’adore les parfums de cette marque car je trouve qu’ils sont captivant et surtout ils tiennent toute la journée ! Ils ont des odeurs originales et que l’on ne retrouve pas partout ! Je conseil fortement</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bv-content-data">
                           <div class="bv-content-product-questions">  </div>
                           <div class="bv-content-tag-dimensions">  </div>
                           <ul class="bv-content-data-recommend-yes">
                              <li class="bv-content-data-label-container"> <span class="bv-content-data-icon" aria-hidden="true">✔</span> <span class="bv-content-data-label">Oui</span>, </li>
                              <li class="bv-content-data-value">  je recommande ce produit. </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="bv-content-actions-container bv-active-feedback">
            <div data-bv-v="feedback:17" class="bv-feedback-container">
               <div class="bv-content-feedback-vote bv-content-feedback-vote-active" role="group" aria-label="Utilité du contenu">
                  <div class="bv-content-feedback-vote-request">
                     <p>Avez-vous trouvé cet avis utile ?</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="bv-content-feedback-btn-container"> <button type="button" class="bv-content-btn bv-content-btn-feedback-yes bv-focusable" aria-label="2&nbsp;personnes ont trouvé cet avis utile. Oui, review de Jo56 est utile."> <span aria-hidden="true"> Oui · <span class="bv-content-btn-count" aria-hidden="true">2</span> </span> </button> <button type="button" class="bv-content-btn bv-content-btn-feedback-no bv-focusable" aria-label="0&nbsp;personne a trouvé cet avis inutile. Non, review de Jo56 n'est pas utile."> <span aria-hidden="true"> Non · <span class="bv-content-btn-count" aria-hidden="true">0</span> </span> </button> </div>
                  <div class="bv-content-feedback-vote bv-content-feedback-vote-active"> <button type="button" class="bv-content-report-btn bv-focusable" aria-label="Marquer «&nbsp;Excellent&nbsp;» de Jo56 comme inapproprié.">   Signalez un contenu inapproprié  </button> </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="bv-inline-form-container"></div>
         <div data-bv-v="secondaryContentList:15" class="bv-secondary-content-list">
            <ol data-bv-v="secondaryContentItemCollection:16" class="bv-content-list bv-content-list-clientresponses" role="presentation">
            </ol>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ol>
```

For example, I tried the following:

```
response.css('li.data-content-id').extract()
```

But it gives me back an empty array.

## Update

After looking through other elements of the page in the developer tools it seems that the data I am looking for is given in a batch.json document:

[image]

The data was generated from this request:

> https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/batch.json?passkey=iohrnzjadededr160osgfvimy&apiversion=5.5&displaycode=3232-fr_fr&resource.q0=products&filter.q0=id%3Aeq%3AP618001&stats.q0=questions%2Creviews&filteredstats.q0=questions%2Creviews&filter_questions.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&filter_answers.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&filter_reviews.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&filter_reviewcomments.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&resource.q1=questions&filter.q1=productid%3Aeq%3AP618001&filter.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&sort.q1=lastapprovedanswersubmissiontime%3Adesc&stats.q1=questions&filteredstats.q1=questions&include.q1=authors%2Cproducts%2Canswers&filter_questions.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&filter_answers.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&limit.q1=10&offset.q1=0&limit_answers.q1=10&resource.q2=reviews&filter.q2=isratingsonly%3Aeq%3Afalse&filter.q2=productid%3Aeq%3AP618001&filter.q2=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&sort.q2=submissiontime%3Adesc&stats.q2=reviews&filteredstats.q2=reviews&include.q2=authors%2Cproducts%2Ccomments&filter_reviews.q2=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&filter_reviewcomments.q2=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&filter_comments.q2=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Afr_FR&limit.q2=5&offset.q2=0&limit_comments.q2=3&callback=BV._internal.dataHandler0

Since I want to automate it, I wonder if and how I can reproduce it from the information it contains or that I can obtain from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses class selector. And your html tells that `data-content-id` is attribute. Not familiar with scrapy to tell if it has something for attribute selection but you could use XPath instead

```
response.xpath('//li[@data-content-id]')
```

Answer (score 0):

`data-content-id` could also have some other values for some other types of content on the page so above xpath may fetch unwanted sections.

Following css should work:

```
response.css('[itemprop="review"]').get()
```

Or if you really want to include data-content-id then I believe we should use:

```
response.css('[data-content-id*="Reviews-"]').get()
```

This will fetch all elements whose data-content-id attribute includes Reviews-. We are using a wild card here because the number following Reviews looks like an ID that will vary for each review element.

Answer (score 0):

Required data **is not presented in html code of the page!!** 
It was loaded by separate Api call and rendered by javascript.

 To see original html code You need to (in chrome) use View source option
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> 
 - not Inspect ->Elements.

Additional Info - > Scraping dynamic content ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html))

Comment: That sounds like a promising doc! Thanks! Even if I’m not familiar with reproducing data provided by JavaScript

Comment: Indeed, it comes from a request to an API. I shared the web request that leads to the docs I'm looking for. However, I wonder how I can reproduce it from the webpage or the information I obtain when loading it.